# Wrapped java.net.UnknownHostException: file: unknown error Cause: file: unknown error for PTC thingworx service script to parse xml file

Tags: javascript, thingworx

I tried the following javascript on PTC thingworx service
var params = {
url:"file:///C:/Users/ShaurabhKumar/Documents/MATLAB/AGENT.xml",
timeout:160
};

Getting the following error
Wrapped java.net.UnknownHostException: file: unknown error Cause: file: unknown error

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the xml file on a server and provide a valid URL path.